# get d at end when i print array

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to send my form data to php using ajax which is successfully happening, form1 contains table my problem is when i send the form data after serialize to php through ajax and when i print it on

> php side it gives me character 'd'

i don't knw why this is happening

```
jQuery('.finialize').click(function(){
                var dte={};
                var $form = $("#form1");
                dte = getFormData($form);
                dte['info']='disrepency';
                console.log(dte);
                senddata(dte,"../controller/register.php");

});



        function getFormData($form){
            var unindexed_array = $form.serializeArray();
            var indexed_array = {};

            $.map(unindexed_array, function(n, i){
                indexed_array[n['name']] = n['value'];
            });

            return indexed_array;
        }


        function senddata(data,url){
            jQuery.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: url,
                  data: {'data':data},
                  dataType: "json",
            })
            .done(function(result){
                if(result['errCode'].hasOwnProperty('-1')){
                    alert(result['errMsg']);
                }
                else{
                    alert(result['errMsg']);
                }
                console.log(result);
            })
            .fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus) {
                    console.log( "failed due:"+ textStatus);
             })
        }
```

**PHP Side**

```
foreach($dt as $key=>$val){
            echo $val['InvoiceNo'].":";
            echo $val['ContractID']."\n";
        }
```

I get output as

```
148523:1/14S/0
1485231:1/14S/0
1485232:1/14S/0
1485233:1/14S/0
d:d
```

> why am i getting d:d

This my php side data of what i get from ajax

```
Array
(
    [input_[1] => Array
        (
            [InvoiceNo] => 148523
            [ContractID] => 1/14S/0
            [Amount] => 
            [SetOFF] => 
            [Comment] => 
            [childInvoice_1] => Array
                (
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [InvoiceNo] => 148523

                            [ContractID] => 1/14S/0
                            [Amount] => 
                            [SetOFF] => 
                            [Comment] => 
                            [Line_item] => 144
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [InvoiceNo] => 148523

                            [ContractID] => 1/14S/0
                            [Amount] => 
                            [SetOFF] => 
                            [Comment] => 
                            [Line_item] => 149
                        )

                )

        )

    [input_[2] => Array
        (
            [InvoiceNo] => 1485231

            [ContractID] => 1/14S/0
            [Amount] => 
            [SetOFF] => 
            [Comment] => 
        )

    [input_[3] => Array
        (
            [InvoiceNo] => 1485232

            [ContractID] => 1/14S/0
            [Amount] => 
            [SetOFF] => 
            [Comment] => 
            [childInvoice_3] => Array
                (
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [InvoiceNo] => 1485232

                            [ContractID] => 1/14S/0
                            [Amount] => 
                            [SetOFF] => 
                            [Comment] => 
                            [Line_item] => 146
                        )

                )

        )

    [info] => disrepency
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change your foreach like below, and test once.:-

```
foreach($dt as $key=>$val){
           if($key != 'info'){
                 echo $val['InvoiceNo'].":";
                 echo $val['ContractID']."\n"; 
            }
        }
```